# Firestore transient condition issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I just upgraded my Flutter project dependencies to the latest version. After upgrading to the latest version it started throwing an exception whenever I try to fetch data from Firestore. However I am able to fetch data from a real time database.

**Error**:

> E/flutter ( 3036): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.

Tried the following solutions:

1. Wiped out the data from the Android emulator.
2. Make sure the emulator is connected to the internet.

**cloud_firestore: ^3.1.15**